# Remove <a> tag from HTML

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I'd like to remove the  tag from my HTML.

I have the following HTML:
`<h1><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>& Yahoo</h1>`

I'd like to use PHP to convert the above to: `<h1>& Yahoo</h1>`

Can someone explain how I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php).

```
strip_tags('<h1><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>& Yahoo</h1>', '<h1>');
```

The result will be `<h1>Google & Yahoo</h1>`. In case you really want the result `<h1>& Yahoo</h1>`, you can do it in this way:

```
preg_replace("@<a[^>]*?>.*?</a>@si", '', '<h1><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>& Yahoo</h1>');
```

Comment: @michaelmcgurk output will be `Google & Yahoo` , is that what you asked in the question?

Comment: Sorry, no it wasn't. Preferred output would be `<h1>& Yahoo</h1>`

Comment: Basically need to fully remove `<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>` from this HTML.

Comment: Hey Sam. I actually need the result to be: `<h1>& Yahoo</h1>` Can you help?